# How can I change the phone number of contact when writing SMS?

Tags: contacts, sms

When I am writing SMS in some existing thread, the SMS is going to be sent to number from which the last SMS came.

But if the contact has more than one number, **how** can I **choose** different phone **number**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **switch** phone numbers in SMS thread.

It is same procedure as you would switch to some online IM channel - use little button with two arrows on it. It is located at the bottom right corner of the screen, in the application bar. When you tap it, **SWITCH TO** page is shown and it contains link **more phone numbers** which (after tapping) reveals other contact's numbers.

This is working supposed the contact *has* more phone numbers.